# How to pull docker images inside restricted network

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I want to pull a certain number of images from docker hub. But since I cannot access the docker hub from my organization internet, what are the ways by which I can pull those images.

The error is:ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the answer of @omernaci, you can either download the image on a separate environment, or use a proxy (prefered, as it applies to usual restrictions like isolating servers from the public internet):

## Using a proxy

If your restricted environment has access to a proxy for this kind of management operations, you may just use it [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#proxy-configuration):

- `HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:80/" docker pull openjdk`
- **or** `HTTPS_PROXY="https://proxy.example.com:443/" docker pull openjdk` (if using an https proxy)

**OR** configure the proxy setting on docker daemon as explained in https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy and then you may just use `docker pull openjdk` normally

## Downloading the image on a separate environment

You can try these steps, firstly, in an environment with internet access, for example,

- run the `docker pull openjdk` command and download the image.
- then save the image as tar with the following command: `docker save -o <path for generated tar file> <image name>`.
- Copy this tar file to a server that does not have internet access using scp or similar methods.

After you copy,

- run the following command to include the tar file on the server: `docker load -i <generated tar name>.tar`.
- If you want to add a tag to this image, you can run the following command: `docker image tag IMAGE_ID openjdk:latest`.

Comment: Note that "Using a Proxy" would require a docker daemon restart though per documentaion.

Answer (score 4):

You can try these steps, firstly, in an environment with internet access, for example,

- run the `docker pull openjdk` command and download the image.
- then save the image as tar with the following command : `docker save -o <path for generated tar file> <image name>`.
- Copy this tar file to a server that does not have internet access using **scp** or similar methods.

After you copy,

- run the following command to include the tar file on the server : `docker load -i <generated tar name>.tar`.
- If you want to add a tag to this image, you can run the following command : `docker image tag IMAGE_ID openjdk:latest`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in this case would be contact you network administrators and explain them why you need to access this one url. :)

As a workaround:

- If it's not also restricted, VPN might help.
- You could connect to remote computer outside your network and use docker from there.